# How this 'run once' Javascript function working?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I took this code from the [Functional Programming with JavaScript Using EcmaScript 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484226550) book.

This is how the code works. Calling `doPayment()` multiple times don't execute the input arrow function `() => { say("Payment Done") }` due to the internal variable `done` is set to `true` in the first run.

But my understand is that when `doPayment()` is called every time, the variable `done` will be initialized with `false` every time, so the internal arrow function will run every time.

How is it working?

```js
function say(v)
{ 
    document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML += v + "</br>";
}

const once = fn => {
  
  let done = false;
  
  return function() {
    return done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));
  }
}

var doPayment = once(() => {
  say("Payment Done");
});

doPayment();
doPayment();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <span id="out" style="font-family: roboto"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

--------- UPDATE --------------------

It's so discouraging to see how a moderately complex problem like this one is asked to be closed because it is a duplicate of some other question.

Among all the answers, @Sylvester's answer is chosen as the right answer. I have also given my own explanation as the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: off topic: I'd use something more like `const once = fn => (...args) => fn? fn.apply(fn=null, args): undefined;` where `fn` itself doubles as the flag. The main advantage is not that you don't need this extra variable, but that you stop referencing the `fn` so it may be GC and thus avoiding a potential memory leak. Better `const noop = () => undefined, once = fn => typeof fn === "function"?
 (...args) => fn? fn.apply(fn=null, args): undefined:
 noop;` because I don't trust the type of `fn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `once` a local variable `done` is initialized to `false` and a **function** is returned. That function is the one which is bound to `doPayment` and thus each invocation checks and perhaps mutates `done` created in the `once` invocation that created that very function.

If you were to make two:

```
const fnPrint = console.log.bind(null, "test");
const fn1 = once(fnPrint);
const fn2 = once(fnPrint);
```

Here `fn1` and `fn2` are from two different invocations of `once` and thus they will have **different** `done` binding in their closure.

```
fn1() ; prints "test"
fn1() ; does nothing
fn2() ; prints "test"
fn2() ; does nothing
```

Comment: Misspelling in the first paragraph.

Comment: @wonderfulworld `once` gets executed that one time where you are binding `doPayment` so your statement about `once` never being executed is false. Both `fn1` and `fn2` in my example are results from running `once` but calling them will be calling only the function `once` returned and not `once` itself.

Answer (score 2):

> But my understand is that when doPayment() is called every time, the variable done will be initialized with false every time

The line `let done = false` is in the body of `once`, so it executes when `once` is called. The body of `doPayment` is merely `return done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));`, so that's the only thing that is executed when you call `doPayment`.

Comment: In other words, `doPayment()` isn't calling `once()`, it's calling the function returned by `once()`, and `let done = false` is called only in (scope with) `once()`.

Comment: Both the answer and the comment have to be put together to make the right answer. Still, how the ```done``` is mutated and it's scope are not explained.

Answer (score 1):

Your once function is comprised of two function, the first returns the second.

The first function will be executed when you call it initially with your callback function that should only run once. When this happens you are setting the `done` value to `false` and returning the second function.

Now when you call your original function you are no longer executing it directly, instead you are calling the function returned from once (second function).

Here you are looking for a variable assigned to `done`. there is no variable of the name in the scope so the interpreter will look up to the parent scope which is the first function where it will find the variable that it can use in the second function.

```
return done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(null, arguments))
```

what that statement above is doing is if the `done` variable is *truthy* return `undefined` else, set the done variable to true, then call the decorated function with the given context and arguments.

for more look up *closures* and *lexical scoping*

Comment: The second paragraph is incorrect in my opinion. Please look at the other answers and my comments. The function ```once``` is not executed, it is a function alias. What really executed is ```return done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));```.

Answer (score -1):

There is a few JavaScript language features in this example. They are (1) closure (2) comma operator (3) high order functions.

The method `say` is for just display purpose only, so don't have to considered as part of the problem. `once` is a constant function when executed will return another function. The `doPayment` is the high order function.

The `((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));` uses a comma separated operator. The first expression `done = true` is executed first and then the second `fn.appy` is executed next and return the results from the second function.

When the JavaScript execution engine runs the first `doPayment()`, it runs the following:

```
var doPayment = once(() => {
  say("Payment Done");
});
```

It runs the `once` method. At that time `done = false` is executed. Then the *inner function* is returned and that is assigned to the variable `doPayment`. The *inner function* is:

`done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));`

Since the above is inside the `once` function, it has created a closure with the variable `done`.

Now when the `doPayment` (second last statement) is run , so a check is done against `done` which evaluates to `false`. The expression `((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments))` gets executed. This will set the `done` to `true` and executes `fn.apply`.

Now when the `doPayment` is called again (the last statement), the *inner function*

`done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));`

gets executed. This inner function has already a closure which has `done` set to `true` already by the previous execution. So it returns `undefined`.

When the above code is run, the following functions are run:

1. `once` (after the run, `done` is false)
2. `done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));` (after the run, `done` is true)
3. `done ? undefined : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));` (after the run `done` stays as `true`